# Hashmap returning null value in case the key is in Arabic language

Tags: java, hashmap

We are adding key value pairs in a `HashMap` by reading properties file.

While putting key value pair, the key is in Arabic language(Arabic Text) and Value is in English. 
In debug mode we can see the key value pair in the `HashMap`. 
But when we are trying to get values for Arabic key, we are getting `null` value.
We even tried to use `containsKey`, but its also returning `false`.

We have defined property as `button.fetch= \u062c\u0644\u0628` and putting it into the `HashMap` as

```
MessageResources resources = getResources(request, mrc[i].getKey());
Iterator itrEntries = mapKeyMethod.entrySet().iterator();
while (itrEntries.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry objEntry = (Map.Entry) itrEntries.next();
    String strCaptionKey = (String) objEntry.getKey();
    String strMethodName = (String) objEntry.getValue();
    String strCaption = resources.getMessage(userLocale, strCaptionKey);
    if ((strCaption != null) && !mapCaptionMethod.containsKey(strCaption)) {
        mapCaptionMethod.put(strCaption, strMethodName);
    }
}
```

Here value of `strCaption` is Arabic text. And when we try to get value with this key from map, it returns `null`.

Comment: How do you expect any help if you do not show any code?

Comment: Have you tried comparing your present and desired key via `equals` to ensure equality?

Comment: Did you compare the keys that exist in the map with the ones that you are passing ? Are they equal ?

Comment: Please add your code and the property file to give us an impression where the problem could come from. Thank you.

Comment: I would suppose your keys are not `String` but some other class. That class needs to have `equals` and `hashCode` properly overridden.

Comment: Keep in mind that a mere optical check (i.e. the strings "look" identical) doesn't work for debugging. You'd need to check each character since when looking at a string you might miss spaces or have characters that look similar but are not exactly the same - that might be even more the case with "exotic" (i.e. non-ascii) characters.

Comment: There is no notion of language, you have a String and encoding... make sure you do those right...

Comment: When dealing with unicode is it possible for Strings to look the same but not be the same e.g. unicode 202e which is used with Arabic has zero width so you can't see it. You can even use it in Java variable names o_O.

Comment: I have added code snippet in the summary above. Kindly check and revert back.

Comment: First: please avoid [raw types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) and secondly: you might want to use the same encoding. If your properties file is encoded in UTF-8, then your strings should be too.

Comment: The encoding is same at all places.

Comment: Try **java.text.Normalizer** to normalize the Unicode sequence to a fixed variant.

Comment: I just tried and can confirm HashMaps works with those keys, you problem must be by creating or re-creating/reading the key, not the hashmap: Try yourself: `String k="\u062c\u0644\u0628"; Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>(); m.put(k, "value"); System.out.println("contains:" + m.get(k));`